# Werid android emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new at mobile app development. Today I moved the SDK from C: drive to D: and changed the path. everything is working fine but my emulator turn into this weird phone. How can I fix it ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VmUD.jpg)

Comment: Delete the emulator and create it again?

Answer (score 1):

Delete that emulator and create another one. Do it via: Tools \ Device Manager.